# Manage Inventory items in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Data()
    Dim ItemName As Variant
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim i As Long


    ItemName = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Value
    FinalRow = Sheets("Sheet1:Sheet2!B3:B10").Row


    For i = 3 To FinalRow

    If Cells(i, 2) = ItemName And Cells(i, 4) = "" And Cells(i, 5) = "sheet1" Then

  Range(Cells(i, 3)).Copy

  Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            If Cells(i, 2) = ItemName And Cells(i, 4) = "" And Cells(i, 5) = "sheet2" Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3)).Copy

                Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial   Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = ItemName And Cells(i, 3) = "" And Cells(i, 5) = "sheet1" Then
    enter code here
                Range(Cells(i, 4)).Copy
                Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
                Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Else:
                End If
    enter code here
    ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = ItemName And Cells(i, 3) = "" And Cells(i, 5) = "sheet1" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 4)).Copy
            Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
            Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else:
    End If
    Next i       
End Sub

'''the code does not seems to work any help much appreciated
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You cannot just throw in a code and tell *"it does not work"*. This is no free code writing service. In order to get any help here we need at first a proper error description including *where* you get the error and a proper question needs to be asked. Please also have a look at [mcve], it might be necessary that you provide some proper example data too. • If your code does not show any errors explain what it actually does and what you expect it to do. Code without explanation of what you expect from it is pretty useless. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @PEH sorry for my sillyness okay. my question is with my code above is that I need to automatically enter the values of stock items in sheet 1 and sheet 2 after entering the data in sheet 3 of daily inward and outward. my code in vba does not show any error but the desired result could not achieved. I am trying to enter the values through loops with the If then else statements . So is there anything wrong in my code that went wrong?? Thank you for comment much appreciated if you take a look at it.

Comment: As we don't know how your sheets look like and where in your sheets which data is, we don't even know what you are talking about when you say `stock items`, `daily inward/outward` and so on. So it is completely unclear what your code does. One thing is that your code cannot run and must throw an error because of this `Sheets("Sheet1:Sheet2!B3:B10")` which is not a valid sheet name. So The code you show is either not what you actually have in your editor or your sentence *"my code in vba does not show any error"* can't be true. At least that is a fact. So you need to give much more information.